# How to access sales results when iTunes Connect is closed for the holidays?

Tags: app-store-connect

December is the best time for app developers, but Apple closes down iTunes Connect for more than a week making it impossible to access sales figures?
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you have a programming question?

Comment: This is a software development question.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan there is an itunesconnect tag which has 28k followers. I think plenty of developers will find it useful.

Comment: It may be more suitable for programmers.stackexchange.com than for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed by accident that it is possible! This is how I do it:

1. **iAd is NOT closed** so you can login to your iAd account via [iad.apple.com/itcportal](https://iad.apple.com/itcportal/) this should **authenticate** you for iTunes Connect.
2. Enter this address to **bypass ITC login** (and the holiday message): https://reportingitc.apple.com

You can see that the address is not https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ which is blocked with the  holiday message.

I use Chrome for this but should work with any browser

I can access all sales data from 22 December, I still cannot access any other pages.

[image]

Comment: The bypass login URL isn't working for me, in neither Safari nor Chrome.

Comment: I tried it again and it did not work first. I cleared all cache and tried again. iTunes connect expires much faster and sometimes randomly but an iAd session works for hours. It works now

Answer (score 0):

If you already use a sales-data scalping service, like **Distimo Monitor** then they may be able to pull through some data from iTunes Connect APIs, however I'm guessing you haven't set anything like this up.

The bypass login provided by yourself doesn't work for me, although I certainly hope it does for you.

Please be wary of the fact that any reports you manage to gain access to have the chance of being incomplete or innacurate as Apple made it clear that reporting will not be available/reliable during the Holiday Shutdown.

If you set up [Distimo Monitor](https://analytics.distimo.com) now you may be able to gain access to sales data from today onwards: I'm also pretty sure it can't grab access to historical data.

You've only got another day left!

*Note:* I personally use Distimo Monitor and have slightly sketchy results the past few days, albeit seemingly reliable.

Comment: I use AppAnnie but it stopped providing results since 21 Dec