# Get iTunes vendor ID while iTunes Connect is down?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

iTunes connect is down for the holidays. To get sales reports or any data, we are supposed to use their Autoingest java client. This requires our vendor ID. The only way I can find to get the vendor ID is from iTunes Connect, which is down! Is there any way to get this from XCode or from our app store listings?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access sales results when iTunes Connect is closed for the holidays?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047950/how-to-access-sales-results-when-itunes-connect-is-closed-for-the-holidays)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047950/how-to-access-sales-results-when-itunes-connect-is-closed-for-the-holidays), then you can find the vendor ID under the reports drop down.

Comment: This is ridiculous but it worked. I logged in to iAd, it gave me a bunch of errors, then I went to the itc url, it showed me sales trends (awesome). Then I clicked the reports tab and my vendor ID was in the dropdown.